# Swift : Tableview numberOfRowsInSection didn't return the indexpath.row I asked for

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want the numberOfRowsInSection to return the number of comment at index path and one post only in the first cell this return one cell for post and one for comment neglecting the number of comment in the var.
What's wrong?

**Update :**
This is a details view controller : when user tap the post to view comments it present the post in the first cell and the comments down.

I got a problem the first cell is ok but the comments cell present only one cell no matter how many string in the variable what's wrong ?

```
  var comments = ["comments","comments","comments"]
        var posts = ["posts"]
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    return 2
}


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    if indexPath.row == 0 {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postCID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! postCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "fff"
    }


     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("commentCID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! commentCell
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel?.text = comments[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

I tried this one too > didn't work

```
       func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
       if (section == 0) {
         return 1
       }
        return comments.count
    }
```

**this is the simulator output**

[image]

Comment: I do not understand what you want to do. Can you please edit the original question to make this more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally !**

```
 class CommentVC: UIViewController {

    var comments = ["comments","comments","comments","comments","comments","comments"]
    var posts = ["posts","posts"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
//    
//     func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
//        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
//        // Return the number of sections.
//        return 1
//    }
//    
//     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
//        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
//        // Return the number of rows in the section.
//       
//        if (section == 0) {
//            return posts.count
//        }
//        return comments.count
//    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 2//One Section for the post and One Section for the comments?
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        if (section == 0) {
            return 1
        }
            return comments.count

           }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //post's section == 0

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postCID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! postCell
            cell.textLabel?.text = "fff"
        }

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("commentCID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! commentCell
            // Configure the cell...
            cell.textLabel?.text = comments[indexPath.row]
            return cell



    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want your post and comments to be cells in a single section, then your numberOfRowsInSection should be `posts.count + comments.count`.

If you want two sections (one for the post and one for the comments), you need to return 2 from numberOfSectionsInTableView: and have your tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: look like your edit

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       if (section == 0) {
        return posts.count
       }
       return comments.count
 }
```

Comment: in the var comments there are 3 strings it shows only one ,Still! I want post cell to show only one cell + the comments cell to show comments.count

Comment: what seems the problem if the code is ok and the storyboard are hocked up correctly !

Comment: Sorry, you want the comments cell to show the count of comments? Like, one cell that says "3 Comments"? Or you want a cell for each comment?

Comment: sorry for late respond I want a cell for each comment thanks

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your last update, this is the solution I think you are looking for:

```
var comments = ["comments","comments","comments"]
var posts = ["posts"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2 //One Section for the post and One Section for the comments?
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
       // Return the number of rows in the section.
       if (section == 0) {
           return 1
       }
       return comments.count
}


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //post's section == 0
    var cell: UITableViewCell!
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postCID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! postCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "fff"
    }
    else {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("commentCID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! commentCell
        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel?.text = comments[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: there is an error in cellForRowAtIndexPath use of unresolved identifer 'cell' pointed to the last return cell

Comment: I add var cell:UITableViewCell! in cellForRowAtIndexPath to counter the error I get fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Sorry! I can't believe I missed that. Does the edit fix the problem?

Comment: no fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value